# Expansion of the Debye function

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, power-series

I need a BIG help with this, I need proof and derive the following expansions of the Debye functions for $$n \geqslant 1$$

$$  \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n}}{e^{t}-1} dt = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-kx}\left[\frac{x^n}{k}+ \frac{nx^{n-1}}{k^2} + \frac{n(n-1)x^{n-2}}{k^3} +...+ \frac{n!}{k^{n+1}} \right] $$

and... I have no idea how to start, any advice?, please

Comment: $1/(e^t-1)=e^{-t}/(1-e^{-t})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-kt}$, substitute this and integrate each term (by parts, $n$ times). Not writing an answer because this will likely be closed.

Comment: Also, instead of `...` in math mode, please use `\dots` (or `\ldots` or `\cdots`...); try and see the difference.